# Jquery Create "array" of .click functions

Tags: jquery

I have a set of divs:

```
<div id="div_01">ASD</div>
<div id="div_02">ASD</div>
<div id="div_03">ASD</div>
```

I want to create a set of .click functions for those divs:

I tried this:

```
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var picName = "#BSViolenceDiv_0" + i.toString();
        //alert("\nI have for i: " + i + ": " + picName);
        $("#div_0" + i.toString()).click(function(){
             $("#div_0" + i.toString()).animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
         });    
    }
```

It does not work because i ends up being 3.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm super confused by your questions.

Comment: You do not need to create a whole bunch of `click` event handlers. Just use a class and bind that click handler to that class instead just like the answer of @Zakaria.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be better if you could use a global class instead (e.g `my_div`) like:

```
<div id="div_01" class="my_div">ASD</div>
<div id="div_02" class="my_div">ASD</div>
<div id="div_03" class="my_div">ASD</div>
```

Then attach `click` event to this class so you don't need to loop through all the `div`'s :

```
$(".my_div").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:1}, 1000); // "$(this)" refer to the clicked div
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".my_div").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
})
```

```css
.my_div{
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_01" class="my_div">ASD</div>
<div id="div_02" class="my_div">ASD</div>
<div id="div_03" class="my_div">ASD</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable *i* has reached its final value before the code in the click event handler is executed, so it will always use that final value in the click handler, and as a consequence the selector `"#div_0" + i.toString()` will not refer to the element clicked on.

But you don't really need *i* to refer to the clicked element. Just use `this`:

Replace:

```
$("#div_0" + i.toString()).animate
```

with:

```
$(this).animate
```

That is the essence of your error. But as others have stated you don't need to create a separate handler for each `div`. Just create one for all, for instance by creating a class for them, and use that to select the `div` elements.